# How to display a Cubit state modified in a Widget into another Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, cubit

Im developing a Shopping cart using the BLoC pattern and I got stuck trying to learn the subset Cubit. My main question is how can I display the state of a previously updated Cubit? My flow is the next...

1. On the Product Screen I increase/decrease the items I want to use.
2. To push to change the state, I click a button and send the items as a parameter to the Cubit function.
3. The item list gets updated and I want to get it into another widget that is outside of the Product Screen.

Here is the code:

main.dart

```
void main() {HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
runApp(
RepositoryProvider<AuthenticationService>(
  create: (context) {
    return AuthService();
  },
  child: MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
          create: (context) {
            final authService = RepositoryProvider.of<AuthenticationService>(context);
            return AuthenticationBloc(authService)..add(AppLoaded());
          }
      ),
      BlocProvider<CartCubit>(create: (context) => CartCubit())
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ),
)
);
}
```

product_screen.dart

```
BlocBuilder<CartCubit, List<Item>>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                return Row(
                  children: [
                    _shoppingItem(0),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 2,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                        color: Color(0xFF48AD71),
                      ),
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          for (int i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
                            items.add(widget.item);
                            print('something');
                          }
                          context.read<CartCubit>().addToList(items);
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                            Icons.shopping_bag),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            )
```

cart_cubit.dart

```
class CartCubit extends Cubit<List<Item>> {
CartCubit() : super([]);

void addToList(List<Item> items) {
state.addAll(items);
emit(state);
print(state);
}
}
```

What I should add on my Cart Screen so I can get the value of the Cubit State? Also, do this should be better handled by using a bloc instead of cubit?

Edit: Based on the comment of Loren.A I removed the BlocBuilder of my ProductScreen and I added it to my CartScreen.

```
class _CartScreenState extends State<CartScreen> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
SizeConfig().init(context);
return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: BlocBuilder<CartCubit, List<Item>>(
    builder: (context, state) {
      return Column()
...
...
      Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: Text(
                    state.length.toString(), // this is not updating
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'SinkinSans',
                        fontSize: 12.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        color: Color(0xFFC9C9C9)),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Cubit is fine for this. You can update widgets anywhere in your app based on that list just by adding another `BlocBuilder<CartCubit, List<Item>>`.  So just add another one to your Cart page and do what ya gotta do inside of it. It will reflect the previous changes.

Edit: Just noticed that it doesn't appear that you're actually rebuilding any widgets in your product screen so that `BlocBuilder` you have is not really doing anything. You can remove that and just use it where you need to reflect that value of the list. You can still fire that `addToList` method without being inside a `BlocBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @Loren.A. I did what you suggested but for some reason is only updating the value once, after that if I want to add more products the value is not being updated in the Cart Page. I checked the Cubit function I'm using to check if there was a problem during the emit but I can see that the values are being store correctly and showing (in a print) that they are always there.

Comment: I just mirrored your setup on my end and am able to continuously update the value on a different page. So not sure what the issue is on your end. If you wanna share the whole project I can have a quick look. 

Besides that, on a side note, if that text widget is the only thing from the Cubit you need to display, then you should move that `BlocBuilder` way down until its only wrapping around the text widget. Otherwise you're rebuilding other stuff unnecessarily.

Comment: Sadly I cannot share the project. But, I notice that the state is being updated is just that the builder is not reloading. So I actually created states instead of having the List as a state and that fixed my problem. However now I'm handling over the states I created. I did some research and I'm not completely sure if this is a bug or it is an expected behaviour because looks like, when the state is trying to get updated, the builder actually rebuild faster than the state, displaying the previous state always.

Comment: I would create a new state called `CartItemsUpdated` to send new items. Also, since the class is stateful, I'd keep `items` as a State property and every time I receive a `CartItemsUpdated` call setState updating the `items` property. That would force the `build` method to be called, updating your interface.